# Get time of a calendar in nanoseconds

Tags: java, time, calendar

Since the Java doc tell me, not to use `System.currentTimeMillis` for comparison, I started using `System.nanoTime` which is fine. 
But I ran into some problems, I have to compare events which are in the past.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, xyz);
cal.getTimeMillis();
```

works fine to get the time in `milliseconds`, but converting it to `nanoseconds` (by multiplying it with 1000000) is far to inaccurate.

**How can I get time of a event in the past in milliseconds?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's your real problem?

Comment: "Since the Java doc tell me, not to use System.currentTimeMillis for comparison" -- this restriction is only for measuring elapsed time between near events. If you are using `Calendar`, by definition you are not measuring elapsed time between near events. The number of nanoseconds since the Unix epoch is a bigger number than a `long` can handle, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, thanks I'll switch back to the time in `milliseconds`. Thanks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Compare the time of two events. The event can be in the past (up to 1970, there is the start of counting the unix time).

Comment: So, you have an initial date (from year to seconds) and an ending date (also from year to seconds) and you want/need to know the amount of time between both?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a problem, e.g the difference in days `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(pastDate - System.currentTimeMillis());`. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Calendar` class in Java doesn't contain nanosecond information. So you can't get that.

<strike>You need to store the nanoseconds as `long` for the event you want to compare later if you need that detail.</strike>: you can't do that too, the nanoTime() is not a representation of current time, but you may still store that to evaluate elapsed time of old processes.

Comment: I can't store the nanoseconds, as long as the time travelling isn't invented. ;)

Comment: so, I'm afraid, you have no ways to retrieve that information.

Answer (score 0):

What data type are you using for the multiplication by 1,000,000 ? Perhaps you should use a BigDecimal, which would be accurate enough for you.

Comment: No need to do this at all if both numbers are using the same multiplicative constant it can be factored out.